# Change browser refresh rate VS Code with Angular,

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

When using VS Code, I noticed that for each small code change, the browser is auto refreshed frequently compared to other editors.

How can I change the browser auto-refresh settings so that the browser wouldn't get refreshed for each code change but with a waiting time(kind of a debouncing effect)?

Comment: You cannot set debounce time for refresh. You can either disable or enable live refreshing with `ng serve --live-reload false` (default value is set to true).

Comment: I noticed that IntelliJ Idea waits for focus to refresh. Is there any way to set something like that in VS code?

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot set this in VS Code. You do not serve the app with VS Code, you use `ng serve` command, which means it's all on Angular CLI side.